# Erro 503 ao tentar baixar extensões no Visual Studio Gallery

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Ao tentar fazer o download de qualquer extensão, o erro abaixo é exibido:

> The extension could not be installed because the following error occurred:
>
> > The remote server returned an error: **(503) Server Unavailable**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não resolve mesmo incluindo uma galeria adicional em configurações.
*Eu consigo acessá-la normalmente pelos navegadores.*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Utilizo proxy para acessar a internet. <s>Não achei onde configurar proxy para estas extensões no Visual Studio.</s> A configuração existe, mas é a mesma dos navegadores (não é específica do VS), não resolvendo.

Como posso resolver este problema e conseguir baixar as extensões?

Answer (score -1):

Você pode configurar o Proxy pela Guia Ferramentas ou Tools se seu VS estiver em Inglês em Opções ou Option depois em Ambiente ou Enviroment WebBrowser depois Internet explorer Options conexões configurações de Lan e configuar o Servidor Proxy.

Comment: Neste caso, é a mesma dos Navegadores, não serve. Retirei o proxy (para testar), e piora nem mostrando os itens online, ou seja, o proxy está funcionando corretamente no VS.